# System.Drawing.Icon path

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, system.drawing

I made a WPF Application and I want to use a NotifyIcon, so I added a reference to System.Windows.Forms and to System.Drawing. I'm using the following code:

```cs
System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();

NotifyIcon Tray = new NotifyIcon();
Tray.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Assets/Icons/icon.ico");
Tray.Visible = true;
Tray.MouseDoubleClick += (s, e) => 
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
};
```

My problem is in the fourth line because the function expects a system path, but I want to add a path to an icon included in my project.

How do I refer to a file in my Project with Windows Drawing Icons?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the `Build Action` property of the icon included in your project to `Content`, and the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer`. Then your current code should work provided that the path is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Accepts both `.ico` and `.exe` files:

```
Tray.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("Assets/Icons/icon.ico");
```